# How to remove a comma from a randomly generated string of items from an array and exclude specific portions of an array from being used in the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I'm creating a password generator for learning purposes.

`first-input` is my input field where I generate the random string of items in the html.

I'm using a function here because there is a button that triggers it to put the random string of items inside the input field.
I found this function in stackoverflow and this function generates 15 random items from the array, but it puts a comma after each item. How do I get rid of the comma? It logs out stuff like:

`J,l,9,),6,A,X,e,_,*,[,x,7,1,&`

And I need:

`Jl9)6AXe_*[x71&`

Now, if I want to take a certain number of items from that array without including a specific group of items like capital letters or numbers, or symbols... how would I exclude them from the array? The goal is to check a box and it excludes that group from the generator. Do I split the array somehow? Make multiple arrays that consist of specific symbols only? Is there a simple way to do this?

```
const characters = [
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
"~","`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=","{","[","}","]",",","|",":",";","<",">",".","?","/"
];

let firstPass = document.getElementById("first-input");

function firstPassword() {
  const shuffledChar = characters.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  const getRandom = (arr, min, max) => {
    const numItemsToPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min
    return arr.slice(0, numItemsToPick)
  }
  firstPass.value = getRandom(shuffledChar, 15,15)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A decent way to organize the different character sets would be to put them into a multidimensional array (characterSets).  You can then grab the inputs, loop through them, and if they are not checked, include their corresponding character subset by using the array method [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).  My example below is assuming that we have 4 inputs with class of 'my-checkbox'.  To get the output without commas, use the array method, [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).  Also, for shuffling arrays, please see [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array).  The shuffledChar array is not truly random.

```
const characterSets = [
    ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],
    ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"],
    ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
    ["~","`","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","=","{","[","}","]",",","|",":",";","<",">",".","?","/"]
];

let firstPass = document.getElementById("first-input");

function firstPassword() {
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.my-checkbox');
    let selectedCharSets = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
            selectedCharSets = selectedCharSets.concat(characterSets[i]);
        }
    }

    const shuffledChar = selectedCharSets.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
    const getRandom = (arr, min, max) => {
        const numItemsToPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min
        return arr.slice(0, numItemsToPick)
    }
    firstPass.value = getRandom(shuffledChar, 15,15).join("")
}
```